# Textbox value from inside gridview not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and within it there is also another gridview as a templete filed, inside the nest gridview there is a textbox as a templete filed, now there is another button on nested grid too, when ever i press the button and i try to get the textbox value it's always empty, am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Please post your code, or else we won't know if you are doing anything wrong.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake, each time i click the button on the grid a postback is triggered and since i fill my gridview at pageload, the gridview is blinded again and thus all values inside the grid is gon.

Comment: @Neha's answer seems to be the way out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onload use

```
 if(!ispostback)
//bind grid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below code format in `Page_Load` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    { 
        gridView.DataSource = yourDataSource;
        gridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```